# SASS:How do I get width & height of a parent in a nested decleration?

Tags: css, sass

I'd like a child element to inherit the same dimensions as its parents. How can I access the parent width and height? Something like this:

```
 .thumb {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;);
    .content {
    width: $parent.width()};
    height: $parent.height()}}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
.thumb {
    width: 120px;
    height:120px;
    .content {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        display:block;
    }
}
```

You may or may not need `display:block` in the parent element as well, depending on its type.

Comment: This isn't related to sass especially and it do not solve the problem when you actually want to avoid % size. For calculation with padding for instance. Probably easiest way would be to use variables but then they are global.

Answer (score 24):

None of these replies are answers to the question asked, really.

Say I’m working with `rem`s or `vw`s or some obscure properties, and need to explicitly define say, a `line-height`, and not a `height`.

The answer, as far as I know, is that it isn’t possible to dynamically fetch parent property values. But, you can store the height in a variable in the parent scope, and then re-use it further down the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

```
.thumb {
    display: block;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
}
.content {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box; /* if you need borders and/or padding */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Somtimes plain css helps:

```
.thumb, .thumb .content {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your case, you could try to use border-box CSS3 property:

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing0

BTW, it doesn't work on IE <= 7. More info here:
[SASS: width: 100% - 20px - is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126580/sass-width-100-20px-is-it-possible)

Answer (score 0):

You can set width and height in variable with sass.

```
.thumb {
    $thumbSize: 120px;

    width: $thumbSize;
    height: $thumbSize;
    .content {
        width: $thumbSize;
        height: $thumbSize;
    }
}
```

If you want to change width and height then just change the variable value. Its more easy to handle.

Comment: This adds nothing over the existing answers.