# SASS: width: 100% - 20px - is it possible?

Tags: css, sass

I use padding in many of my projects, and it would be handy if I could substract the padding from the width, it is possible ?

if:

```
width:100%;
```

and

```
padding: 20px;
```

=

```
100% - 40px ?
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `box-sizing: border-box` to make the `padding` be counted as part of the `width`.

```
div {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Here's a quick demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/DNs2u/

More info:

- http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing
- http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing0
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: ..although with the exact demo I created, it would be simpler to omit `width: 100%` and then there's no need for `box-sizing`: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/DNs2u/1/

Comment: How broad is the support across browsers for the box-sizing?

Comment: @Andrew Harry: Check the link in my answer: http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing. All browsers except IE6/7 support it.

Comment: If you use Compass, there's a helper for box-sizing: http://compass-style.org/examples/compass/css3/box_sizing/

Answer (score 7):

```
width: calc(100% - 40px);
```

more calc() uses:
[CSS Tricks: A Couple of Use Cases for Calc()](https://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/)

Answer (score 1):

Nope, sadly. Since SASS compiles on the server into straight CSS, and the CSS is rendered by the client, you can't get that effect with SASS. In other words, it's not until the browser interprets the CSS that you know what 100% is, and that's long after SASS has had a chance to compile.

If you need to know the inner width of a block element to the pixel level server side, before the page renders, really the only way to do it is to have a fixed width layout. Lots of sites do it - like this one for example - so I would look at that as an option.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible with sass

Those things are possible with javascript.

```
$('#element').width($(window).width() - 40)
```